# Converting hex number to mac address

Tags: python, hex

I have a hex number `0x000e96a001064d60`. I need to convert this to a mac address. I was told that this represents the IEEE_Complete address.

To my eye it seems one nibble too many here. How do I convert this to MAC address

I have tried

```
value = value[2:] if len(value) % 2 == 0 else "0" + value[2:]
return ":".join(value[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(value), 2))
```

what I get is

```
"00:0e:96:a0:01:06:4d:60
```

To me it looks too long to be a `MAC address`

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: MAC addresses are usually 48 bits (6 octets), but this “MAC” address is 64 bits (8 octets). That is confusing.

Comment: @liv2hak: where exactly did you get this address from?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that with RegEx to split the string:

```
import re

v = 0x000e96a001064d60
s = '{0:016x}'.format(v)
s = ':'.join(re.findall(r'\w\w', s))
print(s)
# -> 00:0e:96:a0:01:06:4d:60
```

Or, without RegEx:

```
v = 0x000e96a001064d60
s = '{0:016x}'.format(v)
s = ':'.join(s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, 16, 2))
print(s)
# -> 00:0e:96:a0:01:06:4d:60
```

A classic MAC address has 6 bytes. This is a EUI-48 address.
But here, you have 8 bytes. So it looks like a EUI-64 address. But, bytes 4 and 5 should be FF:FE…

Answer (score -1):

`0x000e96a001064d60` represents an <del>[EUI-64 identifier](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/network-infrastructure-documents/understanding-ipv6-eui-64-bit-address/ta-p/3116953)</del>. *Guess not, an EUI-64 needs to have `FFFE` as the middle bytes.*

EUI-64 identifiers are used in: ([source](https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/mac-lookup/))

- FireWire
- IPv6 (Modified EUI-64 as the least-significant 64 bits of a unicast network address or link-local address when stateless auto configuration is used)
- ZigBee / 802.15.4 / 6LoWPAN wireless personal-area networks

To convert that number to a MAC format in Python use:

```
mac = '0x000e96a001064d60'
mac = mac.split('x')[1].zfill(16)
':'.join(''.join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(mac)]*2)
```

Output:

```
00:0e:96:a0:01:06:4d:60
```

Comment: The OP has the code to convert. He is just not convinced by the output.

Comment: That doesn’t look like an EUI-64: the middle two bytes aren’t FFFE (per the Cisco page you linked to).

Comment: @nneonneo good catch .. wonder if it's a "real" IPv6 address, or just looking like one.